# Apache ThreadsPerChild increase not applying

Tags: multithreading, apache

I installed WAMP and am using Apache 2.2.17 on my windows 7 box. Have a lot of boxes connecting to it to request work etc etc.

The apache server crashed on me twice because it said

```
[warn] Server ran out of threads to serve requests. Consider raising the ThreadsPerChild setting
```

I messed around with the httpd-mpm and this is my current configuration within that file

```
#
# Server-Pool Management (MPM specific)
# 

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
#
# Note that this is the default PidFile for most MPMs.
#
<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
    PidFile "logs/httpd.pid"
</IfModule>

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
<IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
LockFile "logs/accept.lock"
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

#
# Only one of the below sections will be relevant on your
# installed httpd.  Use "apachectl -l" to find out the
# active mpm.
#

# prefork MPM
# StartServers: number of server processes to start
# MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxClients: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# worker MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          4
    MaxClients          300
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadsPerChild     250
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# BeOS MPM
# StartThreads: how many threads do we initially spawn?
# MaxClients:   max number of threads we can have (1 thread == 1 client)
# MaxRequestsPerThread: maximum number of requests each thread will process
<IfModule mpm_beos_module>
    StartThreads            10
    MaxClients              250
    MaxRequestsPerThread 250
</IfModule>

# NetWare MPM
# ThreadStackSize: Stack size allocated for each worker thread
# StartThreads: Number of worker threads launched at server startup
# MinSpareThreads: Minimum number of idle threads, to handle request spikes
# MaxSpareThreads: Maximum number of idle threads
# MaxThreads: Maximum number of worker threads alive at the same time
# MaxRequestsPerChild: Maximum  number of requests a thread serves. It is 
#                      recommended that the default value of 0 be set for this
#                      directive on NetWare.  This will allow the thread to 
#                      continue to service requests indefinitely.                          
<IfModule mpm_netware_module>
    ThreadStackSize      65536
    StartThreads           250
    MinSpareThreads         50
    MaxSpareThreads        500
    MaxThreads            3000
    MaxRequestsPerChild      0
    MaxMemFree             100
</IfModule>

# OS/2 MPM
# StartServers: Number of server processes to maintain
# MinSpareThreads: Minimum number of idle threads per process, 
#                  to handle request spikes
# MaxSpareThreads: Maximum number of idle threads per process
# MaxRequestsPerChild: Maximum number of connections per server process
<IfModule mpm_mpmt_os2_module>
    StartServers           2
    MinSpareThreads        5
    MaxSpareThreads       10
    MaxRequestsPerChild    0
</IfModule>

# WinNT MPM
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in the server process
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum  number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadsPerChild     250
    MaxRequestsPerChild    0
</IfModule>
```

The issue is that even though I increased the number of threadsperchild it still says this in the error log

```
[Tue Apr 12 00:26:10 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) PHP/5.3.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Apr 12 00:26:10 2011] [notice] Server built: Oct 18 2010 01:58:12
[Tue Apr 12 00:26:10 2011] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3580
[Tue Apr 12 00:26:10 2011] [notice] Child 3580: Child process is running
[Tue Apr 12 00:26:10 2011] [notice] Child 3580: Acquired the start mutex.
[Tue Apr 12 00:26:10 2011] [notice] Child 3580: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue Apr 12 00:26:10 2011] [notice] Child 3580: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

Why doesn't my threadsperchild setting apply and work? It seems to default back to 64...

Answer (score 9):

If you still have this problem, you need to uncomment this line in httpd.conf:

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
```